# Box.com API Get Information About a Folder - Stops working

Tags: box-api

Simple and quick question :-)

My application (https://www.box.com/services/rubibox) stops working. I use this request for retrieve items in folder http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-get-information-about-a-folder and this request stops working yesterday. Is maintance on Box.com Apiv2 or request was removed from Apiv2?

PS: I know that is possible to use http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-retrieve-a-folders-items but this is not good for me because not contain current folder informations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a recent API change a call to `/folders` no longer includes the `item_collection` by default.  You must now ask for the `item_collection` in the request:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID?fields=item_collection
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Comment: Yeah, i using fields. I forgot write that the response from server is empty. I mean all keys is NULL and list of files is empty [] . I made update of my application two weeks ago. Works perfect until yesterday.

Comment: Can you post a trace of the request you're executing?

Comment: This is my request which work until yesterday https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/%1?fields=size,sequence_id,etag,name,sha1,parent,path_collection,description,shared_link || item_collection missing ;) . Tomorrow i will try add item_collection to this request.

Comment: Today i'll not be at PC so tomorrow i post here the response from server.